# How to order by date from new to oldest?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm having trouble sorting a list of dates from newest to oldest. Any ideas?

My code is as follow:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Prices()
    {
        var allResults = from result in _context.Reviews
                         orderby result.Date descending
                         select result;

        return View(await allResults.ToListAsync());

    }
```

I receive the following error message:

> CS1061     'DbSet' does not contain a definition for
>   'OrderByDescending' and no extension method 'OrderByDescending'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: *are you missing a **using** directive or an assembly reference?*

Comment: I'm a fool. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add using `System.Linq;`

That will solve your problem.